# Make error when trying to run C++ code with OpenCV dependency

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to build a C++ repo to run locally and am running into this error:

To build, I cd into the directory and run `make`. However, I get this error:

```
make
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/opencv4   -c -o RPPG.o RPPG.cpp
In file included from RPPG.cpp:9:
./RPPG.hpp:14:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/objdetect.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I'm new to C++ (normally code in python), and I already have OpenCV installed, which I regularly use for python. I looked into my OpenCV source files and I have objdetect.hpp stored. I switched the g++ command to reference the location where my opencv files are stored, which is here:

`/Users/asi/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include/opencv2`

And ran the following command:

`g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I/Users/asi/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include/opencv2   -c -o RPPG.o RPPG.cpp`

but I still get this error:

```
In file included from RPPG.cpp:9:
./RPPG.hpp:14:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/objdetect.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your include path looks wrong in the second example.

Comment: In your first example `/usr/local/include/opencv4` is there an opencv2 folder inside this folder?

Comment: I tried switching to `/usr/local/include/opencv2`, if thats what you mean. Same error.

Comment: Note in both examples `opencv2` folder has to exist inside the folder that you specify as the include path

Comment: If you added `/usr/local/include/opencv2` then does `/usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv2/objdetect.hpp` exist? Or is it `/usr/local/include/opencv2/objdetect.hpp`

Comment: Its the exact same error as in my post. I do have `opencv2/objdetect.hpp` on my machine, its just located here `/Users/asi/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include/opencv2/objdetect.hpp`

Comment: Then `/Users/asi/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include` is the path you need to add.

Comment: Oh, okay. I dropped `opencv2` and just used the path you recommended and I think it fixed that problem. Now I have a new error, which I probably need to figure out or start a new post, but will share anyway in the event its an easy fix: `In file included from RPPG.cpp:9:
./RPPG.hpp:89:13: warning: private field 'now' is not used
      [-Wunused-private-field]
    int64_t now;
            ^
1 warning generated.`

Comment: That is a completely different problem

Comment: I figured, thanks for your help with my issue!

Comment: You probably want to ignore that warning. It means you have a class but don't use one of the class member variables

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I meant just disregard the message. It's saying your code does not use a variable that you defined as part of your class. If you really don't plan to use it, you can comment it out or delete it however it's difficult to give better advice not seeing the code.